# How to Resuspend cells at cell density of 8 log CFU/ml of bacterial culture whose CFU/ml i don't know at 600nm, also it doesn't grow well on MRS agar?

Tags: microbiology, microbiome

According to procedure after 24 hr growth of Lactobacillus delbruckii subsp lactis in MRS broth, I have to resuspend it at 10 raise to power 8 CFU/ml and then inoculate it further. But it doesn't grow well on MRS agar and I haven't observed its proper colonies. Is there a way by spectrophotometer that I can know how to determine its CFU at 600nm after 24 hr without having to do spread plating?

Comment: Hi and welcome. I think you might be in a pickle, but I may well be wrong. I am NOTNOTNOT a pathologist or a microbiologist, not even close, *but*... I *think* a CFU has to be a viable cell capable of forming a colony, and doesn't include cells that can't form colonies (I may well be wrong!) So visualization might be inaccurate. Are you familiar with Modified Fishman Units?nI hope someone who knows more about this than I do posts a suggestion for researching this issue.

Comment: You should be able to get colonies on various types of agar, but particularly MRS under anaerobic conditions. What are your growth conditions? There is no way to determine the CFU without doing the plating as you will find variations based on exactly which strain you have and your growth conditions, media variations etc.